# Show firebase notifications when android app is open and with high priority

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, nativescript

I am using [nativescript-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase) for the APP and I get the notifications when the app is closed.

However, if the app is open I don't get any notifications. Is there any way to force showing push notifications even when the app is open or do I have to create a custom notification with sound within the app?

Another problem that I have is the way the push notifications are displayed. I use [Laravel-FCM](https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM) to send push notifications from the server-side, I have the priority set to 'high' and everything else set to default but when I receive the notification to the android device there is no floating notification, only a badge icon and a notification in the notifications center.

In the app notifications settings, there is **Miscellaneous** Notification Category with **Importance** set to Default, Vibration set to OFF and LED Light is also OFF but if I manually change those settings then firebase notifications appear with floating notification and vibration.

Any way to actually make these notifications with high priority by default?

P.S. The device I am testing on is Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro

Comment: Are you buiding this app with native framework?

Comment: @haresh I'm using nativescript-vue for the app.

Comment: Often Remdi has issues as they have their own customised UI on phone. Did you try checking with Nexus / Pixels which runs the unmodified version of Android? Also let's know what version Android you are using in Redmi.

Comment: @Manoj I haven’t tried it on nexus / pixel phones. I could test on virtual device but I know virtual devices have tricky issues with firebase notifications so therefore, I’m testing on this physical device I have.

The Android version on the device is 9 PPR1.180610.011

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem when using Nativescript-firebase as yours. When the app is open, the push notification is delivered but not shown (see onMessageReceived callback) then you can use Nativescript-local-notification to show the content of the push notification received when app is open.

Comment: I was thinking just that. I wonder if I could use Nativescript-local-notification to show all firebase notifications (including the ones that are received while the app is closed). This would then solve the priority problems I am having.

Comment: @Juky can you please share the code forceShowWhenInForeground , priority not working for me in android

Comment: @iosDev here is the code: var firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");
firebase.init({
    showNotifications: true,
    showNotificationsWhenInForeground: true....})